# Solving matrix Riccati differential equation in Matlab with terminal boundary condition

Tags: matlab, matrix, simulink, differential-equations

In the optimal control tracking problem, there is a Riccati equation of the gain matrix **K**(t) which is:

\dot{**K**}(t) = -**K**(t) **A** - **A**^{T} **K**(t) - **Q** + **K**(t) **B**  **R**^{-1} **B**^{T} **K**(t)

At the final time of Tf, the terminal boundary condition **K**(Tf) is given.

Edit: After consideration, I think the question is how to numerically backward integrate the gain matrix with the given terminal boundary condition and save the results in a lookup table to obtain the solution over the interval [t0,Tf]  for further computations in Simulink ?

Answer (score 1):

The numerical solution to this equation is found in the book [***Optimal Control Systems***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0849308925)

For example, the following is an excerpt of the technique:

```
E=B*inv(R)*B';  % the  matrix  E  =  BR^{-1}B' 
% 
% solve  matrix  difference  Riccati  equation  backwards 
% starting from  kf  to  kO 
% use  the  form  P(k)  =  A'P(k+1)[I  +  EP(k+1)]^{-1}A  +  Q 
% first  fix  the  final  condition  P(k_f)  =  F 

Pkplus1=F; 
p11(N)=F(1); 
p12(N)=F(2); 
p21(N)=F(3); 
p22(N)=F(4); 

for  k=N-1:-1:1, 
    Pk  =  A' *Pkplus1*inv(I+E*Pkplus1)*A+Q; 
    p11 (k)  =  Pk(1); 
    p12(k)  =  Pk(2); 
    p21(k)  =  Pk(3); 
    p22(k)  =  Pk(4); 
    Pkplus1  =  Pk; 
end
```

For further information, you may check this book. It's great and informative.